# Sending stuff with PHP and POST

Tags: php

how I SEND stuff with PHP and POST? (not how to grab, or how to send from html... but how to send from PHP... the particular PHP script is not even running in a webserver, neither is part of a web-page).

I looked everywhere on google, but I keep finding examples of how to use a html form, and how to use $_POST to get the results...

Comment: I like Daniel's answer, but as an alternative, maybe you can leverage another binary on your server.  Just make sure it's secure (doesn't arbitrarily send POSTed data from user input).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use libcurl for that.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```